# Define a group leader in a LDAP posixgroup

Tags: ldap

I'm trying to find out if it's possible to define a certain member in a posixgroup as the group leader/manager of that specific group.

I tried looking for some objectclasses with this purpose, but my search came up empty.

I imagine something like this:

```
dn: cn=someGroup,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: posixGroup
objectClass: awesomeClassSolvingMyIssue
gidNumber: 10000
cn: someGroup
groupLeader: user2
memberUid: user1
memberUid: user2
```

If it's not possible to achieve this, I would greatly appreciate advice on other ways to solve this issue.

Comment: What functionally differentiation is this member to have from the other members?

Comment: @84104 This ldap structure is part of a SSO backend which will among other things, serve some Django apps. In this case, the group leader will have elevated permissions regarding group management for that specific group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The POSIX fields are technical fields to manage permissions for the operating system and the group leader is not relevant for this purpose.

You have some options:

- Add the `groupOfNames` object class and (ab)use it's `owner` attribute for your purpose or browse through other schemas to find something fitting.
- Design a schema with your own object class and attributes.

Comment: The groupOfNames/owner method is the one that I use. However, it requires converting from nis.schema to RFC2307bis.schema.

Comment: The RFC2307bis.schema sounds like a good solution. I'll give that a go!